# Delete all records with id higher than X in CKAN

Tags: python, postgresql, ckan

I'm trying to use the datastore_api in CKAN (ckan.org) and want to delete all records with an id higher than X - my goal is simply to delete ALL records without deleting the table.

Docs:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.5.1/maintaining/datastore.html?highlight=filter#ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_delete

Running the API with

```
'filters': {'_id': '0'}
```

does work, but setting

```
{'_id': '>0'}
```

or

```
{'_id': '*'} fails.
```

How can I empty a table in the datastore without deleting the table?

The SQL generated in CKAN is:

```
...9b89-7ab1c36c8e00" WHERE ("_id" = '*') ...
```

So it make sense why it fails, but I don't know how to use the API calls with either wildcards or "higher than".

This seems to be the code:

```
def delete_data(context, data_dict):
    validate(context, data_dict)
    fields_types = _get_fields_types(context, data_dict)

    query_dict = {
        'where': []
    }

    for plugin in p.PluginImplementations(interfaces.IDatastore):
        query_dict = plugin.datastore_delete(context, data_dict,
                                             fields_types, query_dict)

    where_clause, where_values = _where(query_dict['where'])
    sql_string = u'DELETE FROM "{0}" {1}'.format(
        data_dict['resource_id'],
        where_clause
    )

    _execute_single_statement(context, sql_string, where_values)

...

def _where(where_clauses_and_values):
    '''Return a SQL WHERE clause from list with clauses and values

    :param where_clauses_and_values: list of tuples with format
        (where_clause, param1, ...)
    :type where_clauses_and_values: list of tuples

    :returns: SQL WHERE string with placeholders for the parameters, and list
        of parameters
    :rtype: string
    '''
    where_clauses = []
    values = []

    for clause_and_values in where_clauses_and_values:
        where_clauses.append('(' + clause_and_values[0] + ')')
        values += clause_and_values[1:]

    where_clause = u' AND '.join(where_clauses)
    if where_clause:
        where_clause = u'WHERE ' + where_clause

    return where_clause, values
```

Comment: Have you read the relevant bit of code?

Comment: Added comment in question...

Answer (score 1):

***NOTE:*** There was a bug found because of this question. There seems to be no way to delete just the data from a `datastore`. A pull request to fix this was already sent at https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2885.

*Your question's title asks how to delete all records with id higher than X, but in your question you said that your goal is "simply to delete ALL records without deleting the table." This is what I'm answering here.*

According to the documentation at http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.5.1/maintaining/datastore.html?#ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_delete:

> ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_delete(context, data_dict)
>   Deletes a table or a set of records from the DataStore.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - resource_id (string) – resource id that the data will be deleted from. (optional)
> - force (bool (optional, default: False)) – set to True to edit a read-only resource
> - filters (dictionary)– filters to apply before deleting (eg {“name”: “fred”}). **If missing delete whole table and all dependent views. (optional)**

Emphasis mine.

If you don't pass a `filters` attribute, CKAN will delete the table itself. If you pass filters as `{}`, it'll delete all table's contents.

Comment: Parsing 'filters': {} actually deletes the table, not just the rows.

Comment: This line:

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/f74575024a472085db2c8238d8f0ff71d888ffaf/ckanext/datastore/db.py#L1169

Is removing the filters argument from data_dict. This means that when db.delete is finally called here:

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/f74575024a472085db2c8238d8f0ff71d888ffaf/ckanext/datastore/db.py#L1169

... that the database will always be deleted.

This is a bug, I will send a PR to correct this shortly.